# Selecting Currently Active File C# to show on status bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, extension-methods, intellisense

I have followed this guide > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165473.aspx to the point where I am able to create a Menu Item to the visual studio menu bar.

However, I have read about active tabs and such. I was wondering if it is possible to write code into the methods such that it will show me the current tabs that I am on?

I have created a few extensions but nothing much to the extent of finding an active filepath.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

[image]

Except that, it would potentially appear at the status bar below or a popup.

[image]

Where should I be using the DTE/DTE2 objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS you can refer to `DTE` or `DTE2` objects. They represent VS IDE.

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
string document = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;
```

you would have to add a reference to the `EnvDTE` assembly.

`DTE` has been superseded by `DTE2`.
You can get reference to `DTE2` as follows

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
dte2=(EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
```

The code is for `VS2013`

Comment: Where do I add those objects to in my code? Sorry, I am quite new to this and have read about DTE/DTE2 objects only.

Comment: @leonardchan you can use `DTE` or `DTE2` in your code. Once you create an instance of `DTE2` you can then use it to find the active document.

Comment: Hi sorry, I don't see where I could use DTE/DTE2 in the above example for the TopLevelMenu tutorial. I've added the reference but it's not working.

Comment: @leonardchan you are making a VS extension right? so you would have a `vsix` project. When do you want this `file path` to show I mean  do you want to show it in the status bar on some user action?

Comment: Refer to this link [Extending the status bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166795.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Yes I am making a VS extension and would want it to show in the status bar. I looked at the example and do not see an instance where DTE or EnvDTE80 is being used.

Comment: @leonardchan you want to show the current file path in the status bar right? So need to follow that link and also follow the code snippets given above, you may have to merge them in a suitable manner to get the path showing on the status bar

Comment: private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
            string document = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;

Comment: Hi. I have added the snippet to MenuItemCallback and added             DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
            string document = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;

Comment: @leonardchan and? what are the results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125470/discussion-between-leonard-chan-and-miguel-sanchez).

Comment: DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            string document = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName; 

Was what I have. Running it, I was unable to get anything on the status bar. Do I have to use the second snippet of code you have shared earlier as well?

Comment: @leonardchan no you need to use one of those. what version of VS are you working on 2012 or 2013?

Comment: I apologise for not mentioning earlier, I am working on VS 2015... does that come with any restrictions?

Comment: @leonardchan then you better use `DTE2` it is newer and will have support for more features. Also you may have to change `VisualStudio.DTE.12.0` is the init to your vesion I believe it may be `14.0 `but you may have to check that

Comment: I have changed accordingly however, upon click of the active tab or when I am in the active tab, it does not show. This is what I have now. I apologise for asking too much. 

private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
            dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0");

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("showing?");

            // Stop the animation. 
            //statusBar.Animation(0, ref icon);
        }

Comment: @leonardchan you may have to handle the tab changed event in VS

Comment: I will try to figure it out from here. I do not know how though. I came across [Visual Commander](http://https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html) and would eventually want to create my own vsix extension.

Comment: @leonardchan look into the [DTE Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.events.aspx) docs